# how to make integer as Key and List as Value in Map in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, hashmap

I have this input

```
arr = [1,2,1,3,4,2,4,2]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is make elements of the given list as keys of a map and its indices as values in the form of a list.

Like this :

```
mp = {1:[0,2],2:[1,5,7],3:[3],4:[4,6]}
```

And what will be the time-complexity for this?

Answer (score 2):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for pos, num in enumerate(array):
   result[num].append(pos)
```

Time complexity is *`O(n)`*, there is only one loop and all things in the loop (looking up thing in dictionary, appending an item) are constant wrt. the number of items.

Comment: Any specific reasons to use defaultdict ?

Comment: @AnshumanSharma it lets you just append to the list at the key without having to worry about whether the key was in the dictionary already or not.  There are other ways of accomplishing the same thing, but this is easiest.

Comment: I think this is providing exactly the opposite of what was asked for.  You need to swap `pos` and `num` in the append.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2]
mp = {
    num: [i for i, k in enumerate(arr) if i == num]
    for num in set(arr)
}
```

or normally:

```
arr = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2]
mp = {}

for num in set(arr):
    mp[num] = []
    for i, k in enumerate(arr):
        if k == num:
            mp[num] += [i]
```

Sorry, i do not know much about the time complexities stuff, but naturally two loops, so O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
arr  = [1,2,1,3,4,2,4,2]
d = {}
for n in set(arr):
    d[n] = [i for i, x in enumerate(arr) if x==n]
```

or

```
import numpy as np
arr  = [1,2,1,3,4,2,4,2]
arr = np.array(arr)
d = {n:np.where(arr==n)[0].tolist() for n in set(arr)}
```